# Using bengottlieb / Twitter-OAuth-iPhone, running on iPhone device

Tags: iphone, xcode, twitter, oauth, device

Got the source ["bengottlieb / Twitter-OAuth-iPhone"][1]

I added the existing folder "Twitter+OAuth" to my project.
Fixed Target to include libxml2.dylib and libOAuth.a
Fixed Header & Library Search Paths, just like DEMO project did.
Building itself is fine. Only showing warnings about MGTwitterEngine's parsing issues.

However, when I try to run on my actual device, it's showing following error messagess at below.

Can anyone guide how to use bengottlieb source? This is the best source for my project, and I can't find the right way to add this to my project in Xcode. Thank you.

```
run
Running…
Ignoring packet error, continuing...
gdb stack trace at 'putpkt: write failed':
0   gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x0018dc33 remote_backtrace_self + 54
```

Comment: Full error message is not added. Basically, it seems to showing device issues. But I have no clue what exactly this is about.

Comment: I'm running in to this same "Ignoring packet error, continuing..." issue, though not using the library you mentioned. Restarting the device doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the answer from the source creator, and he guided me to simply restart device, and it worked.

Thank you, Mr. Gottlieb
[(GitHub Profile: http://github.com/bengottlieb)](http://github.com/bengottlieb)

Answer (score 0):

제가 아는 동혁이 형인가요? 저도 시뮬레이터에서 동작하는데 디바이스에서는 다른 에러 메시지를 보이네요. 트위터 서버인 척을 한다고. MGtweeterEngine 사용했습니다. 앗! 저도 리붓하고 나니 동작하네요. 감사합니다.

Comment: 아마 우리 나이가 비슷한게, cnook 님이 아시는 분과 저는 다른 것 같네요 ㅎㅎㅎ 암튼 StackOverflow 에서 만나서 반갑습니다. 화이팅 하세요~